# How can I solve "UserWarning: set_ticklabels() should only be used with a fixed number of ticks" in Seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, xticks

I faced a warning message when trying to rotate xticks of seaborn.lineplot.

At first, I tried to run `set_ticks`, but `ax` doesn't seem to have this function. I also checked `FixedLocator`, but haven't figured out how to use it.

Can anyone teach me how to remove this warning message?

#### Environment

- Python 3.12.1
- matplotlib 3.8.2
- pandas 2.2.0
- seaborn 0.13.2

#### Sample Data

https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/sumanthvrao/daily-climate-time-series-data?select=DailyDelhiClimateTest.csv

#### Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data: pd.DataFrame = pd.read_csv("DailyDelhiClimateTest.csv", 
                                 parse_dates=["date"], index_col="date")

ax: plt.Axes = sns.lineplot(data=data)
ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

#### Warning Message

```
UserWarning: set_ticklabels() should only be used with a fixed number of ticks, i.e. after set_ticks() or using a FixedLocator.
  ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)
```

Comment: If that's the case, is there a good way to convert `ax.get_xticklabels()` to a static array?

Comment: If you only want to change the rotation, you can do it with `ax.tick_params("x", labelrotation=45).  See https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.tick_params.html

Comment: Indeed, you really need `ax.tick_params("x", labelrotation=45)`.  The problem with `ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=45)` is that the tick labels are only created when the plot is finally drawn, so `ax.get_xticklabels()` doesn't make sense yet.